# Delphi stream read error when loading image

Tags: image, delphi, fault

My program loads a lot of images, but i have a problem with 1 image that used the print-screen button to copy it, from a game, however it is bmp, like all the rest. Whenever i run the program, it says project1.exe raised exception class Ereaderror with message 'stream read error' process stopped....

The code is this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var path, destination:string;
begin
path:=paramstr(0);
destination:=extractfilepath(path)+'Leagueoflegendsdesktop.bmp';
image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(destination);
end;
```

Which is correct. What do you suggest me?

Comment: What have you done to ensure that the bitmap file is valid? For example, load it in another program and re-save it. Does the other app generate an error on reading the file? Does the re-saved copy open in your delphi app without an error?

Comment: i used photoshop cs6, but that's the only picture i had problem with, all the rest editted by photoshop were successfully loaded

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation is that the file is not a valid Windows bitmap (maybe the file is truncated). Or perhaps the file uses some esoteric format not supported by Delphi. Is it using run-length encoding, for example.

If the file did not exist you'd get a different error, one that indicated that no such file exists. So, the file exists but cannot be loaded. Ergo, it's not a Windows bitmap.

Step 1 to diagnose this is to look at the format of the file. Load up the bitmap file header and check that the values make sense. Probably the easiest way to do this is to step through the VCL code when running your program under the debugger. Enable the Debug DCUs option so that you can do that. Set a breakpoint in `TBitmap.ReadStream` in the `Graphics` unit and take it from there.

Having said all that, it may just be easier for you to avoid trying to debug the problem at all. If you can load the image into an image editor, simply save a new copy of the image in a format that will be read by Delphi. For example a plain vanilla Windows bitmap, or, even better, a PNG file which will admit compression.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i figured it out, i've made a search on that and i found out that photoshop sometimes can cause this problem, so everyone who uses photoshop, save this image as jpeg, then open with other program save it as bmp  (recommended 24 bit)

Comment: So, does this answer your question then? And btw, better to use non-lossy format like PNG as in-between format.